# Need to resolve the issue- play-mailer API

Tags: java, playframework, guice, email-client

When I'm trying to upgrade MailClient for Play Framework 2.5 from API which is deprecated. I've followed the documentation and created the required files and given entries in required files as per documentation. After everything is set, when I try to run my application I'm getting the following error on the browser network response tab. Help needed to resolve the following error.

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;    
import play.libs.mailer.MailerClient;


private final MailerClient mailerClient;    

@Inject
    public SMTPProvider(final ConfigurationManager configuration, 
     MailerClient mailerClient) {
        this.from = configuration.getString("email.from");
        this.mailerClient = mailerClient;
    }
```

**I'm getting this error in browser network response column**

```
Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for play.libs.mailer.MailerClient was bound.
while locating play.libs.mailer.MailerClient
for parameter 1 at com...email.SMTPProvider.(SMTPProvider.java:31)

while locating com...email.SMTPProvider
for parameter 1 at com...conf.EmailProviderGuiceProvider.
(EmailProviderGuiceProvider.java:23)
at com...conf.AppModule.configure(AppModule.java:89)

1 error
```

Comment: The issue is that the instructions should be assuming a basic configuration and something is just not right. I think you should install the new version of the software and then config your application, do the required changes in both as per your needs and be happy (probably)

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for the quick update. But I tried to configure it as per the [documentation](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer) . So, I've no clue left with.

Comment: In thous cases I delete the software and re-install it because with time is common to change configurations and install other components that might be interfering, but the error looks like you are missing the configuration of where the code for `play.libs.mailer.MailerClient` is located, try deleting it (the configuration), saving and redoing the routing to where your code is, sometimes things get stock like that...

Comment: Please update the title to write a meaningful title. Describe the technical problem you face in a short sentence. The current title means absolutely nothing about your technical problem.